# How can I insert an image in to Microsoft Word programmatically?

Tags: delphi, ms-word

We need to insert a **signature image** into a **Word template document**. We are doing the mail-merging, etc. fine. But how do we insert an image programmatically?  The signature image is not always the same.

We are using Delphi. But I can translate a C solution (if it does not use C libraries).

I also need to know how to position the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var
Word, Doc: Variant;
begin
  Word := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
  Doc := Word.Documents.Open('C:\test\word.docx');
  Word.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture('C:\test\sign.bmp');
  Doc.Save;
  Word.Quit;
end;
```

Comment: Is there any way to position the image ?